# How to give a 3d shape (to the bars) to 2d grouped bars plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this df:

```
         YEAR  CODE      ANOM%
    0    1964  152101 -85.294118
    1    1965  152101 -62.352941
    2    1965  152111 -85.862069
    3    1966  152101 -81.352941
    4    1966  152111 -77.873563
    ..    ...     ...        ...
    108  2020  152101 -38.823529
    109  2021  152101 -59.352941
    110  2021  152111  74.137931
    111  2022  152101 -95.235294
    112  2022  152111 -76.436782

[113 rows x 3 columns]
```

With this code i'm creating a table to plot grouped bars:

```
df.sort_values('YEAR', axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

years = df["YEAR"].unique()
prv= df["CODE"].unique()

#Categorizacion
df["YEAR"] = pd.Categorical(df["YEAR"], categories=years)
df["CODE"] = pd.Categorical(df["CODE"], categories=prv)

#PIVOT THE TABLE
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(
    df, #df
    values="ANOM%", 
    index="YEAR", 
    columns="CODE", 
    aggfunc=np.sum 
)

df_pivot.columns = df_pivot.columns.add_categories('AVERAGE')
df_pivot['AVERAGE']=df_pivot.mean(axis=1).astype(int)
```

And with this code i'm creating the figure and plotting the grouped bars:

```
fig = plt.figure('Grouped Bars', figsize=(16,10), dpi=100)
ax1 = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.85, 0.75])

df_pivot.plot(kind='bar',
              color=['black' if col!='AVERAGE' else 'red' for col in df_pivot.columns],
              fontsize=12.0, zorder=1, edgecolor='black', linewidth=2,
              alpha=0.7, ax=ax1, depthshade=True)
```

I want to give to my bars a 3D effect (i don't wanna plot a 3D graphic bar, i just want my bars to have a slightly 3D effect). I tried with this parameters:

```
edgecolor='black', linewidth=2,
                  alpha=0.7, depthshade=True
```

but with `depthshade=True` i got this error: `AttributeError: Rectangle.set() got an unexpected keyword argument 'depthshade'`

How can i have a 3d shape graphic bars? Matplotlib version: 3.7.0
PD: If i still have to plot a bar graph in 3d, how can i do it?